# Is there a better way to plot multicolor lines in R than splitting the data?

Tags: r

Sequential portions of my time series are under different treatments, and I'd like to separately color a line connecting observations in each portion.

For example, in the series under treatment A I'd have a red line, and in the succeeding series under treatment B I'd have a blue line.

`plot(response, type="l",col="treatment")` failed - all observations were connected with a line the same color.

This listhost posting proposed just splitting the data by treatment and then separately plotting each subset on the same plot. (http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Can-R-plot-multicolor-lines-td791081.html).

Is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two popular more elegant ways. One is to use the `ggplot2` package. Without more information it's hard to advise you other than look at help or examples in various places. The other is to check out the function `matplot`. That will require you to first restructure your data as a matrix but it can easily do what you want. Keep in mind that while it says in the help, "Plot the columns of one matrix against the columns of another", the x-axis matrix can be a vector the same length as one column of a matrix containing your line information. The function will just recycle the x vector.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I have a feeling `matplot` won't be a lot of use here because the x-axis values will not be consistent for each segment to be plotted.

Comment: `matplot` can take separate x's for each y in columns of a matrix

Comment: But each x will have to be the same length though, as matplot doesn't take a list as an input, only a matrix.

Comment: Columns can be padded out with NA's, so `matplot` can handle unequal length vectors.

Comment: Ok, but that does require a fair bit of data manipulation to get to.

Comment: I'm not sure that making a matrix of `NA` and filling the columns is a fair bit of manipulation, but OK, it is some manipulation. It's still an option. We don't know the segments aren't the same length.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative using `Map` that avoids manually plotting segments:

```
dat <- data.frame(treatment=rep(LETTERS[1:2],3:4),
                  response=c(6,5,2,1,5,6,7),time=1:7)

plot(response ~ time, data=dat, type="n")
Map(
  function(x) lines(response ~ time, data=x, col=x$treatment),
  split(dat, dat$treatment)
)
```

[image]